# create an array

Tags: bash, array, assignment

I want to learn about arrays and how to assign values to them, so I found [this tutorial](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays)

While running the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
$names=([0]="Bob" [1]="Peter" [20]="$USER" [21]="Big Bad John")
echo ${names[@]}
```

I get this error:

```
line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `[0]="Bob"'
line 2: `$names=([0]="Bob" [1]="Peter" [20]="$USER" [21]="Big Bad John")'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove `$` from `names`. Not `$names`  but `names`

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thaks @Cyrus ! That's awesome!

Comment: [20] ?  it does not do what you might expect

Comment: @Skaperen you mean it does not put $USER on the 20th position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When assigning to a variable, don't use the dollar sign:

```
names=([0]="Bob" [1]="Peter" [20]="$USER" [21]="Big Bad John")
```

Comment: if you really wanted to use the dollar sign read up on `eval`